# Continuing PHP code while function runs in background

Tags: php, json

EDIT: I should note this is for an HTML page.

Hi experts,

I'm fairly new to PHP and i have a question which might be relatively easy to answer.

I have a while loop which contains the code to make an API call and load the received json into some variables. This loop has a sleep(5) in it so it checks every 5 seconds. However, i want to run code outside of the loop as well. How should I approach this problem?

```
while(TRUE){

      $fgc = json_decode(file_get_contents($apijson), true);
      echo $last= $fgc["result"]["Last"];
      echo $lastlast
      if($lastlast > $last){
        "doStuff"
      };
      if($last > $lastlast){
        "doDifferentStuff"
      };
      flush();
      ob_flush();
      sleep(5);
      $lastlast = $last;
};

if(possible){
"doStuffHereWhileTheLoopRunsForever";
};
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Use something else than PHP.

Comment: I need php for HMAC

Comment: do you have to check the api every 5 seconds?? anywho. don't use an endless loop in PHP, set up a cron job, but hitting an API every 5 seconds sounds wrong

Comment: I can delay it with a couple of seconds indeed, but i need live data from the API

Comment: For an application like this, check out Gearman, not only is the PHP support good, but as your grow out your application, you can spread the load across many servers. Basically, an endless loop that call Gearman workers based on data received from the API.  That is how we solved a similar use case.

Comment: Can whatever is updating the file notify this script about updates instead?  This seems brittle: what happens if the file is only half-updated at the time you fetch it (mixed data or only partial data)?

Comment: Can't you just have two different php processes?

Comment: I must understand the right use of this but in last words you are searching of an async PHP?like as reactPhp...What you want it's a parallel execution...
https://medium.com/async-php/event-loops-84978080389c

Comment: But maybe i don't understand but you can do an Ajax call that call the php that calls the api for example this ajax call can be executes every buhh 1 minutes, every minutes in the ajax call will be called the php and the while loop, after you can execute all the code you want in the page, but not all the code in a file but in 2 differents files...or no?one file with the loop of the api will be call with an ajax call and after the second file it's your code out of the loop.